# Internal Server Error 500 when i use cookies

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, remember-me

When the user get login route:

```
$app->get('/admin/login', function() {

    User::checkCookie();

    $page = new PageAdmin([
        "header"=>false,
        "footer"=>false
    ]);

    $page->setTpl("login");
});
```

I created the method "checkCookie" to know if the client has cookies :

```
public static function checkCookie() {

        if (!isset($_COOKIE["username"])) {
            header("Location : /admin/login");
        } else {
            header("Location : /admin");
        }
    }
```

However, when i access the route appears the " 500 Internal Server Error ", so I would to know what's happening and how to solve it.

With the method "login" is effetuated the user's login and if the " remember  box" is checked the method will create the cookies.

```
public static function login($login, $password, $rememberCheck):User
    {

        $db = new Sql();

        $results = $db->select("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE deslogin = :LOGIN", array(
            ":LOGIN"=>$login
        ));

        if (count($results) === 0) {
            throw new \Exception("Não foi possível fazer login.");
        }

        $data = $results[0];


        if (password_verify($password, $data["despassword"])) {

            $user = new User();
            $user->setData($data);

            $_SESSION[User::SESSION] = $user->getValues();

            return $user;

        } else {

            throw new \Exception("Não foi possível fazer login.");

        }

         if($rememberCheck=='1' || $rememberCheck=='on')
        {
            setcookie("username", $login, time() + 3600, "/");
            setcookie("password", $password, time() + 3600, "/");
        }
```

[print - error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTYKU.png)

Comment: Have you tried to turn on error reporting in php to view exact error? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/2665475

Comment: Setting a password in cookies is a real bad idea.

Comment: and what's the best way to save these user's information )

Comment: Once the user has logged in and you have set the session you should not need the user's password. If at any point after that you need their credentials for some explicit operation you should request them again using another form.